# Unix command CP to copy a file to multiple directories

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, cp

I have folder structure like this:

```
/home/
   /folder1/
      /backup/
   /folder2/
      /backup/
   /folder3/
   /folder4/
      /backup/
   /folder5/
```

(As you can see, no all directories "folder" have a directory "backup")

I need to copy the script "checker.php" to all "backup" directories only.

"checker.php" is at:

```
/home/checker.php
```

I am using this command:

```
cp /home/checker.php /home/*/backup/checker.php
```

But it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cp` command doesn't allow multiple destination directories.

A way forward is to loop through the folders:

```
for d in /home/*/backup; do 
    cp /home/checker.php "$d"
done
```

Comment: If it's a text file, maybe also look at `tee`, which does allow you to write to multiple destination files.